# Accessing .rodata/.rel.data.ro

Tags: binary-analysis, android, elf

Analyzing an android ELF binary. How/where does something access a specific area of .rodata or .rel.data.ro? Have tried using objdump, rabin2, readelf, etc and I can't seem to figure out how it is internally accessed/used.